# 'Workers and Workloads'

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

What are 'Workers and Workloads' in Distributed Computing? Heard about these terms recently. Are these general terms or vendor-specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Workloads* are described in [this article](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-handle-workloads-in-cloud-computing.html) as:

> an independent service or collection of code that can be executed. Therefore, a workload doesn’t depend on outside elements. A workload can be a small or complete application.

*Workers* are computers that you program to perform automatic tasks within the cloud. Tasks like monitoring databases, checking files on servers, etc. All within the cloud.

I found [an article](http://thoughtsoncloud.com/2011/12/migration-to-cloud-it-is-all-about-workloads/) which writes about IBM introducing a *workloads in the cloud* concept, but I think the first part of my response covers the thing you're curious about.